# Can I get multiple subdomains for different dns?

Tags: domains, subdomain, dns-servers

I have a domain registered with a domain vendor and hosting provider. I tried out with [000webhost](http://www.000webhost.com) as hosting service, so I changed my domain settings to the **000webhost dns addresses**.

At 000webhost I can generate as much **subdomains** as I want. So I can get for example:

- subdomain1.mydomain.com
- koala.mydomain.com
- mexico.mydomain.com
- ...

But as 000webhost is Apache, PHP MySQL based here comes one of my needings:

What if I want to have something like:

- rubyonrails.mydomain.com
- nodejs.mydomain.com

That's **subdomains for different technologies**. And I assume I'd look for a free hosting service based on such different technologies. I'd need to deal with their dns for each subdomain.

As I know, the immediate solution to this are **CNAMES**, I contacted my domain service provider and they told I should change dns settings to theirs and they'd create as much CNAMES registers and I wanted but I'm not sure this would fix the main hosting with 000webhost, the subdomains for different technologies and the subdomain for a blog hosting.

What's the right solution for this and, if anyone knows, does godaddy permit to create any CNAMES registers as intended?

Answer (score 2):

If you have your domain pointed to 000webhost nameservers then you should be able to edit your host files/dns settings somewhere within their control panel.

In their control panel im pretty sure there is an option named or either similar to "DNS Zone Editor". Here you can create as many records as you need and can point them anywhere.